# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() - Crud Generator

Tags: laravel, foreach, crud

estoy usando Laravel Crud Generator y al momento de querer insertar un registro me aparece el siguiente error se que esta en el foreach pero no se como corregirlo

```
Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View: C:\laragon\www\sistema\resources\views\admin\perfil\form.blade.php)
```

el codigo de mi vista es:

```
<div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('category') ? 'has-error' : ''}}">
    <label for="category" class="control-label">{{ 'Category' }}</label>
    <select name="category" class="form-control" id="category" >
    @foreach (json_decode('[multi-empresa: Multi-empresa, empresa: Empresa]', true) as $optionKey => $optionValue)
        <option value="{{ $optionKey }}" {{ (isset($perfil->category) && $perfil->category == $optionKey) ? 'selected' : ''}}>{{ $optionValue }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
    {!! $errors->first('category', '<p class="help-block">:message</p>') !!}
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prueba asi, el formato del json no es correcto:

```
json_decode('{"multi-empresa": "Multi-empresa", "empresa": "Empresa"}', true);
```

de todos modos no es buena practica realizar ningún tipo de método o función dentro de una declaración de un foreach, deberías de asignar el valor a una variable primero Ej:

```
   @php $options = json_decode('{"multi-empresa": "Multi-empresa", "empresa": "Empresa"}', true); @endphp
   @foreach ($options as $optionKey => $optionValue)
            <option value="{{ $optionKey }}" {{ (isset($perfil->category) && $perfil->category == $optionKey) ? 'selected' : ''}}>{{ $optionValue }}</option>
   @endforeach
```

o ya lo mejor seria mandar desde el controlador los datos procesados para que en la vista no tengas apenas nada de lógica.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu apoyo, seguire tu consejo!